# SQL Won't Update Database

Tags: c#, mysql

This sql statement I check and it works:

> UPDATE `faxcomplete` SET `DATE`= curdate() WHERE `DATE`='0000-00-00'

When I run the code it not update database.  I am a beginner and I don't know how to check if something is wrong:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                           "DATABASE=webboard;" +
                           "UID=root;" +
                           "PASSWORD='';";
      MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
      MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
      MySqlDataReader Reader;
      command.CommandText = "UPDATE `faxcomplete` SET `DATE`= curdate() WHERE `DATE`='0000-00-00'";
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: It's badly formatted. That's one thing wrong.

Comment: do you need to execute the sql?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `ExecuteNonQuery` on your command.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the SQL:

> command.ExecuteNonQuery();

You also need to close the connection once you're done.

> connection.Close();

You do not need the line

> MySqlDataReader Reader;

Answer (score 1):

well one thing i noticed is that your not executing the command or binding it to the connection. I tend to use something like

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("name", connection))
        {
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE `faxcomplete` SET `DATE`= curdate() WHERE `DATE`='0000-00-00'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just noticed yours is using MySqlConnection etc, not sure if this makes a difference or not?